# What does the format from man pages "address#server_name" mean in "DNS=" settings in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf?

Tags: server, dns, systemd-resolved

In the ubuntu [manpages for `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/resolved.conf.5.html) under the "DNSOverTLS=" section, the man pages state

> Entries in "DNS=" should be in format "address#server_name".

I am running a webserver/email server that has a fully qualified domain name, and I am trying to set up a DNSOverTLS unbound DNS server linked to my FQDN.

The man pages are not clear about what should go in your "DNS=" entry in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` when setting up a FQDN as a DNS Server. I'm not exactly sure what the "#" means between the "address" and "server_name", in the "DNS=" entry.

Does this mean I should enter "DNS=Server_IP#FQDN" as in "DNS=123.456.78.9#www.example.com"? What exactly does the hashtag/pound-sign stand for or mean in the man pages?

Answer (score 1):

The `#` is the start of a comment so that would be that it is just a way for you to keep track of what that IP address is that you are putting on that line.  Whether you put the `#example.com` after the IP address or not does not make a difference to how systemd-resolved reads each line.

Comment: Gugh! Im so silly. I should have known this, but thank you.